# Is there a way to fill out the console with print statements like matrix numbers?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an intro for a game i'm making but i want to look cooler than what I usually do for my text games. I'm not sure if this is an awkward question but is there any way for me to "fill" up the console with numbers starting from top left and spreading down and to the right, all the way until the numbers hit the bottom right corner? It gives the feeling that random numbers are being generated and sort of gives it this cool look. Is there any possible way to accomplish this task? I'm thinking currently about for loops and such but i'm not sure if that works.

Comment: You can print out a 2D array to model after matrices. And use Math.random() for random numbers to populate that.

Answer (score 1):

### Cool number method below

---

```
public void coolNumbers(int width){

       for(int i=0; i<width; i++){
         System.out.println();
          for(int j =0; j<width; k++){
            System.out.print("cool number here");   
            }
           }
        }
```

> **NOTE:**  Replace *"cool number here"* with the actual cool number you prefer.

Comment: @Juru he said "spreading top left and spreading down and to the right" he didnt say in what order..

Comment: LOL ok @Juru no where did he mention the matrix, but you seem to know that as well...  while you are at it what is his goal in making all these text games :P

Comment: I'm trying to make them print out at the same time, not one by one, it would start off printing 1 at the top left then 3 numbers right after that, one to the right of the first number, one to the diagonal right, and one below it. Is this possible?

Answer (score -2):

Have you thought about making an applet with a window set to a certain size? This way you can use the window width and height as delimiters in a doubly nested for loop so it will cut off where you want it to.